# How to set in a column the number of data that is under a certain value in a row by several columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, count, bounds

I have this dataframe

```
a <- c(5, 7, 9, 11)
b <- c(-8, -10, -3, -1)
c <- c(-4, -1, -6, 3)
d <- c( "", "", "", "")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

```
    
    a    b  c  d
1   5   8   4   
2   7   10  1   
3   9   3   6   
4   11  1   3
```

I want to set in the "d" column the number of values under a certain bound (<5), something like this:

```
    a    b  c   d
1   5   8   4   1
2   7   10  1   1
3   9   3   6   1
4   11  1   3   2
```

Comment: Do you have negative values as in the example showed or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums` on logical matrix to return the count of columns that are less than 5 in each row

```
df$d <- rowSums(abs(df[-4]) < 5)
```